# Breaking relationship with someone

Tags: hadith, sunnah

Assalamu alaikum brother, I've heard that prophet swaw has said that if any Muslim doesn't talk any other Muslim brother for 3 days none of his good deeds are acceptable. Does this apply to all situations.
I mean to ask let's say a Muslim's sister got raped or murdered by another Muslim or did something worse than this. Is that Muslim brother still obligated to talk to him.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

Forgiveness is something that our prophet tell us to always do as he said that

Abdullah ibn Amr reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Be merciful to others and you will receive mercy. Forgive others and Allah will forgive you.” (Musnad Ahmad),

So I don't think the idea of not talk to some because he did something wrong is good, because verily by you talking to him may let him repent and asked Allah forgiveness for all his sin and we always need to pray for someone like that because this maybe the people that will distory our society

Wasalamu alaikum

Comment: Man! the example he mentioned is : "I mean to ask let's say a Muslim's sister got raped or murdered by another Muslim" and you speak about forgiveness! how about the Prophet not talking with the one who murdered his Uncle Hamaza even after he entered Islam!

Comment: With the case of wahshi bin Harb (r.a) the massager of Allah forgive him and do not what to be remembering the death of his uncle when ever he saw wahshi do that is why the prophet said "I should not see you till the day you are resurrected"